# what does "weight scheme" mean in Recommender system

Tags: recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering

I read different papers in hybrid recommender system 
and in case of combining the prediction the usually use "weight scheme"
what does it mean ?
is it related to  Data Normalization ?
I would like to know because I want to develop a hybrid recommender system by combining prediction from two  recommender system 
Thank u

HERE IS THE resources that I read 
[resources1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYNzh.jpg)
[resources1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkcAp.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Each of your recommender systems make a numeric prediction, let's call them `x` and `y`. To come up with a single prediction though we need to combine these two values in some way. The most simple way is to add them together. However, since each recommender system might make predictions on a different scale (0-1 or 0-10 for example), we also need to weight each value.

Let's say we weight `x` by weight `a`, and `y` by weight `b`, then we have the weighting scheme:

```
prediction = (a*x) + (b*y)
```